# Appending data to Associative or dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a Country select which populates the City select, 
The radius is then added surrounding a particular city.

```
var countrySet = new Array;
var citySet = new Array;
var radiusSet = new Array;
var set;


            function appendCountry(){                   

                if($.inArray($("#businessCountryTarget option:selected").text(),countrySet) === -1) {                           

                $("#businessDisplayCountryInfo").append($("#businessCountryTarget option:selected").text() + "<br>");           

                       countrySet.push($("#businessCountryTarget option:selected").text());
                    set = { country: $("#businessCountryTarget option:selected").text()};

        }

            }



            function appendCity(){                  

                if($.inArray($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text(),citySet) === -1){                          

                        $("#cityContainer").append($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text() + "<br>"); 

                       $("#radiusContainer").append($("#businessCityRadius option:selected").text() + "<br>"); 
                 citySet.push($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text(),+'-'+$("#businessCityRadius option:selected").text());    

                set = {city: $("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text()};
                radius = $("#businessCityRadius option:selected").text();
                set = {radius: $("#businessCityRadius option:selected").text()};

                }       

            }


    function SaveLocations(){
            alert(set['country'] + ' - '+ set['city'] +'-'+ set['radius'] +"<br>");

        }
```

Only the last item are showing in the alert box. the others appear as undefined.

any help please.

Mike

Comment: You can use an object like a map (an associative array without the ordering)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's native objects are key value pairs, which allow you to treat them as maps, roughly equivalent to associative arrays.  So your code above is actually completely valid javascript.

```
var set;
set = { country: "England", city: "London", radius: "10 miles" };
```

you can then access values with

```
set["country"] //"England"
```

or

```
set.city //"London"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I updated the question and the script, I added a new function to alert all the values in 'set'.However it only shows the country.

Comment: you no longer have a clear question though.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  Please rephrase the question with a clear specific problem that you're asking for help with, something more specific than "the code isn't working"

Answer (score 0):

There are associative arrays in JS. You would simply do:

```
var myarray = { "key": "Value" }
```

Answer (score -1):

as long as you declare:

```
var x = []; // you actually don't need new Array()
```

you can treat x as an associative array

```
x.a = 10;
```

This is equivalent to

```
var x = {a: 10};
```

So...

```
x.a == 10; // true

x['a'] == 10; // true
```

Comment: Don't declare things as arrays if you're going to be using them as objects.  It's misleading to the extreme.